# How to go auto start activity in button click android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-permissions, autostart

I want to click button in my app activity and directly open "Auto start"(Setting>Permission>Auto start  ) activity  .How to implement this is my android studio project..

Comment: Did u mean click a button in your activity that will lean to open a navigation menu ?or kind of list in another fragment?

Comment: I updated my questio...  @Ben